# Windbg script: Is there a way to have the currently executed command outputted to the log?

Tags: windbg

I'm using `cdb` with a script file to process crashing inputs to a process (I don't collect dumps).

The command line for `cdb` is as follow:

```
PS> & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\cdb.exe" -g -logo K:\_projects\fuzz\out_test.txt -c "`$`$><K:\_projects\fuzz\crash_info_script.wsc" "K:\_projects\fuzz\bin\simpleTest.exe" -f "K:\_projects\fuzz\corpus\crashes\test_00000000.bin"
```

The script file (`crash_info_script.wsc` in the above command line) passed to `cdb` is simple, as I just want basic info:

```
!analyze -v; .exr -1; lm; k; lmDvmsimpleTest; qq
```

The problem is that the commands themselves are not in the output log. For example, in the latter I have (output of `.exr -1` and `lm`):

```
ExceptionAddress: 00007ffe75721f3e (simpleTest!foo+0x0000000000290f7e)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 000001a435a25000
Attempt to read from address 000001a435a25000
start             end                 module name
00007ff6`df020000 00007ff6`df07d000   simpleTest C (export symbols)       K:\_projects\fuzz2\bin\simpleTest.exe
00007ffe`75250000 00007ffe`7686a000   foo   (export symbols)       K:\_projects\fuzz2\bin\foo.dll            
00007ffe`ac530000 00007ffe`ac5ce000   uxtheme    (deferred)                        
00007ffe`aeb10000 00007ffe`aeb41000   cryptnet   (deferred)             
00007ffe`aeb50000 00007ffe`aeb5a000   VERSION    (deferred)             
00007ffe`b5230000 00007ffe`b5242000   kernel_appcore   (deferred)             
00007ffe`b6c50000 00007ffe`b6c5c000   cryptbase   (deferred)             
00007ffe`b6ce0000 00007ffe`b6d0c000   wldp       (deferred)             
00007ffe`b6f40000 00007ffe`b6f52000   msasn1     (deferred)             
00007ffe`b7100000 00007ffe`b7134000   devobj     (deferred)             
00007ffe`b74a0000 00007ffe`b75ff000   CRYPT32    (deferred) 
...
```

What I would like:

```
> .exr -1

ExceptionAddress: 00007ffe75721f3e (simpleTest!foo+0x0000000000290f7e)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 000001a435a25000
Attempt to read from address 000001a435a25000

> lm

start             end                 module name
00007ff6`df020000 00007ff6`df07d000   simpleTest C (export symbols)       K:\_projects\fuzz2\bin\simpleTest.exe
00007ffe`75250000 00007ffe`7686a000   foo   (export symbols)       K:\_projects\fuzz2\bin\foo.dll            
00007ffe`ac530000 00007ffe`ac5ce000   uxtheme    (deferred)                        
00007ffe`aeb10000 00007ffe`aeb41000   cryptnet   (deferred)             
00007ffe`aeb50000 00007ffe`aeb5a000   VERSION    (deferred)             
00007ffe`b5230000 00007ffe`b5242000   kernel_appcore   (deferred)             
00007ffe`b6c50000 00007ffe`b6c5c000   cryptbase   (deferred)             
00007ffe`b6ce0000 00007ffe`b6d0c000   wldp       (deferred)             
00007ffe`b6f40000 00007ffe`b6f52000   msasn1     (deferred)             
00007ffe`b7100000 00007ffe`b7134000   devobj     (deferred)             
00007ffe`b74a0000 00007ffe`b75ff000   CRYPT32    (deferred) 
...
```

I could use `.printf` after each command but this is quite inconvenient, especially if I change the script.

Comment: Actually, "The $<, $><, $$<, and $$>< commands echo the commands contained in the script file and display the output of these commands." - do you see the commands on the screen but not in the log file if you run the script in WinDbg?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Nope, same behavior if I replace `cdb` with `windbg`, there are no commands in the windbg output window or in the log file (just be clear, as in the question, I just have the output of the commands, not the commands themselves).  A detail which might have some importance: my version is `10.0.19041.685 AMD64` (from the Win10 2004 WDK, I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont have a fuzzable executable this is from a dump so i cant be sure if the behaviour you see is because of that.

use **-cfr file** command instead of **-c** and try

pre dir contents

```
D:\niet>ls -lg
total 153021
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121 156689581 Aug 17 23:49 MEMORY.DMP
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121        22 Sep 17 16:09 foo.wds

D:\niet>file MEMORY.DMP
MEMORY.DMP: MS Windows 64bit crash dump, 4992030524978970960 pages

D:\niet>cat foo.wds
!analyze -v
lm
kb
q
```

command used

```
D:\niet>cdb -g -logo foo.txt -cfr foo.wds -z  MEMORY.DMP

debugger 
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17763.132 AMD64
```

post dir contents

```
D:\niet>ls -lg
total 153053
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121 156689581 Aug 17 23:49 MEMORY.DMP
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121     29738 Sep 17 16:19 foo.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121        22 Sep 17 16:09 foo.wds
```

looking for executed commands

```
D:\niet>cat foo.txt | grep -i ": kd"
1: kd> !analyze -v
1: kd> lm
1: kd> kb
1: kd> q
```

Comment: Thanks a lot blabb! So, I generated a dump from one of the crashes and used your command line and it worked as expected (I could see the commands in the output log). I reused my previous command line but replaced `-c` with `-cfr` and it finally worked! Morale of the story: commands are not outputted if you use `-c`, but they are with `-cfr`. That might be a regression, I kinda remember it worked previously. Problem solved anyway.

Comment: you are welcome . but i vaguely remember running through -c in an earlier windbg and  recall that commands are parsed and passed to apis directly